# What's is the real purpose of having an XML file in Android?

Tags: android, android-xml

folks. I'm beginning Android development and all of the tutoring videos constantly mention XML file. I looked up the meaning of XML which says:"XML was designed to describe data." But WHY is XML needed in Android and in general(please explain in simple understandable words)? Is there any way to create projects w/o XML file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there's *many* places where XML is *mandatory* in Android. You could programmatically build views and keep poorly managed resources if that's what you prefer.

Comment: XML is best part for UI design in android. Although, you can programatically manipulate it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html):

> The advantage to declaring your `UI` in `XML` is that it enables you to better separate the presentation of your application from the code that controls its behavior. Your `UI` descriptions are external to your application code, which means that you can modify or adapt it without having to modify your source code and recompile. For example, you can create `XML` layouts for different screen orientations, different device screen sizes, and different languages. Additionally, declaring the layout in `XML` makes it easier to visualize the structure of your `UI`, so it's easier to debug problems.
>
> Using Android's `XML` vocabulary, you can quickly design `UI` layouts and the screen elements they contain, in the same way you create web pages in `HTML` — with a series of nested elements.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer. To make your life easier.